# Submenu within menu within menu?

Tags: android, layout, menu

On pressing menu button , I have 2 options : Add & more.
On click of more i have 3 options : Organize ,Export & Exit
On click of Organize i want other 5 options.

On click of more i get my submenu. But i want other 5 options on click of organize.How do i proceed???

My code in parts is as follows :
XML file-------------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item    
    android:id="@+id/more"    
    android:title="@string/moreMenu"    
    android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/Organize"
        android:title="@string/Organize" />

        <item android:id="@+id/Export"
        android:title="@string/Export" />
    </menu>  
   </item> 

   <item    
    android:id="@+id/add"    
    android:title="@string/addMenu"  
    android:icon="@drawable/add"/>
   </menu>
```

Java-------------------------

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ToDoList extends Activity {
 Menu menu;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.todolist); 

   }



  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {   
         super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);   
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.categorymenu, menu);

         return true; 


     }  
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {   
         switch (item.getItemId()) { 

         case R.id.more:   
               Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed more!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//(What needs to be done from here)
                    return true;

         case R.id.add:
           Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed add!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          return true;
           }
         return false;
         }
   public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {   
                   return true;   
     }
  }
```

---

Answer (score 2):

As can be seen in [Creating Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) sub menus can not contain sub menus.

You could show a Context menu after clicking on the item in the options menu.
This could show your five more options in a floating view above the screen.

You have to overwrite the onCreateContextMenu to create a ContextMenu and I think you have to call the contextMenu manually in the onOptionsItemSelected method. For resources on how to create the context menu see this [paragraph](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) in the article mentioned above.

To open the ContextMenu you can call [openContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openContextMenu%28android.view.View%29) in your Activity. You may need to register the menuitem before to enable your activity to find the correct context menu.

Comment: OK ! But then what is the functionality that we have on our cellphones such that when we click on 'more' options in contact, i get 'send message' etc & then again clicking send message a small window with 3 options text msg,pic msg, mms pops up. I want a similar functionality.What should i look for?