# Android buttons are moving or navigating from menu activity to submenu activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity

Android buttons are moving or navigating from menu activity to submenu activity,But not moving from submenu buttons to its another submenu buttons. can u explain with code

Comment: Ratna, you're going to have to explain more about your problem. Nobody will be able to answer your question with such little information.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

documentation specifies that it is not possible to create submenus for submenus in android, you'll mostly have to write your own...

this might help - [Submenu within menu within menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989505/submenu-within-menu-within-menu)